# Creating Label vector using Indicator Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Given a binary matrix **M** of size **n x k**, i would like to create a vector **Label** of size **n x 1** such that entry of **Label** should contain the concatenated column index of **M** where its values are **1**

for eg:  If the **M** Matrix is given as

```
M = [ 0 0 1 1  
      0 0 0 1  
      1 0 0 1
      0 0 0 0
      1 1 1 0 ]
```

The resultant **Label** Vector should be

```
 V = [ '34'  
        '4'  
       '14'  
        '0'
      '123' ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it compactly and in a vectorized manner.

```
[nRows,nCols]=size(M);
colIndex=sprintf('%u',0:nCols);

V=arrayfun(@(x)colIndex(logical([~any(M(x,:)) M(x,:)])),1:nRows,'UniformOutput',false)

V = 

    '34'    '4'    '14'    '0'    '123'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) and [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) that returns an N-by-1 cell arrays of strings:

```
>> [r,c] = find(M);  %# Find the row and column indices of the ones
>> V = accumarray(r,c,[],@(x) {char(sort(x)+48).'});  %'# Accumulate and convert
                                                       %#   to characters
>> V(cellfun('isempty',V)) = {'0'}  %# Fill empty cells with zeroes

V = 

    '34'
    '4'
    '14'
    '0'
    '123'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) function or loop to build the strings (replacing empty array indices with '0' after finishing).